# Compute sum of series from product

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $(a_n)_{n \in N}$ be a real sequence. We denote $p = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i$. Is there a closed formula for $\max \{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \} $ as a function of $p$? Can we compute $s = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i$ as a function of $p$?

Comment: Do you know geometric-algebraic inequality?

Comment: What about the case $p=0$.

Comment: Yes I know this inequality..how to use it here ?  And what about p=0 ?  My question is  : can I know S starting from p ?  Thanks for your reactions.